# Homological definition of orientation at a boundary point?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

For a topological manifold $M^m$, an orientation at a point $x \in M$ can be defined as a choice of generator for $H_m (M, M-x)$. For a topological manifold with boundary this definition still makes sense provided that $x$ is not a boundary point.  If $x \in \partial M$ then it's easy to see that this relative homology group is zero. So is there a sensible homological definition of the local orientation at a boundary point? Thank you for considering my question.

Comment: A stupid idea: you could apply the homological definition to the double of $M$ (denoted $\widetilde{M}$ below), and then recast it in terms of $M$. Taking an element of $H_m(\widetilde {M},\widetilde{M}\setminus \{x\})$, you may be able to cut it along $\partial M$ and obtain an element of $H_{m}(M, \operatorname{int} M)$. This may well be nonsense...

Comment: @5pm : Thanks for the feedback.  I thought about looking at the double. It seems dissatisfying because to talk about whether a map is "orientation preserving" you have to extend it to the double.  Then existence of a "good extension" and the independence on the choice of extension become problematic.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are not interested in $H_{n-1}(V,V\setminus\{m\})$ alone which would be an obvious answer, but rather how to lift this into some (possibly relative) homology group of $M$.

Let $x\in \partial M$, and consider a closed contractible neighbourhood $x\in U\subset M$ such that $V=\partial M\cap \partial U$ is a closed neighbourhood of $x$ in $\partial M$. Then there are natural isomorphisms

$$H_n(U,\partial U)\stackrel{\partial}{\to}H_{n-1}(V,\partial V)\stackrel{i_*}{\to}H_{n-1}(V,V\setminus\{m\})$$

And by inclusion again, the first of these groups is naturally isomorphic to $H_n(M,M\setminus\{p\})$ for any point $p$ in $\stackrel{\circ}{U}$.

Thus you have a homological version of how a (local) orientation of a manifold induces an orientation on its boundary and vice versa.